# Running tests with jni4net bridge code using nunit

Tags: java, c#, jdbc, nunit, jni4net

I am writing some tests for a project that bridges a java component into C# using jni4net.  I am able to run the tests using resharper with no issues, but nunit seems to be unable to locate the needed jar

```
        var setup = new BridgeSetup(true);
        string jarPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/bin/lib");
        if (jarPath != null)
        {
            setup.AddAllJarsClassPath(jarPath);
        }
        setup.BindStatic = false;
        Bridge.CreateJVM(setup);
        string jdbcUrl = "jdbc:somedriver:localhost";
        _conn = DriverManager.getConnection( jdbcUrl );
```

The error happens at `DriverManager.getConnection()` looking for a jdbc driver, which is located in the path given `~/bin/lib`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to find a solution to the issue.

NUnit runner by default runs tests in a separate thread, meaning in the java bridge was being initialized on a thread that the tests were not running which caused the tests to not have access to the need .jar files

NUnit runner has a command line option `/nothread` to suppress the use of a separate thread for tests.  More info can be found [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.4)